# JFrame width equals 0 after maximizing

Tags: java

Why it returns 0? What am I doing wrong?

```
public MainFrame() {
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(getWidth() + " " + getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Why re-ask the same question? Your needlessly dividing your discussion is not fair to the volunteers who staff this site. -1 Voting to close

Comment: Because I got no helping answer

Comment: Then improve your original question. Again this is against SO and etiquette rules.

Comment: What can I improve? I have written eveything I could

Comment: You've been asked to provide an SSCCE, and didn't. Provide an SSCCE so that we can reproduce the problem, and tell you how to fix it. As I said, my SSCCE doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: You've not shown enough information for us to explain why your code isn't working. The best thing to do is to post that code in *the original question*, an SSCCE as has been requested.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice? I flagged as duplicate

Comment: But that's whole code... Those 3 lines are whole code

Comment: Then this code isn't even compilable. There is no class here. Just a constructor. And there is no main method, so we can't launch this application. The bug is in the code you don't show. Or it's in your environment. If we could at least execute the same code as yours, we would help YOU diagnose the problem. But you need to post some more lines of code. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you got 0 is because you didn't call any of the pack(), setSize(int, int) or setSize(Dimension). This is only when calling one of these method that the layout of your frame will be computed.

Comment: Actually, I would say that the reason it's 0 is the fact that that is the default size of a frame...But that's being nit picky ;)

Comment: I done pack() and now i returns: width=10 and height=30. Better than 0 but why it still doesnt return correct value?

Comment: 10 and 30 are the default size for a window. That is when it is the minimal (Pretty sure). Make sure you ask for the width and height after it has been packed, set extended state and visible. Also, post more code about what you are adding to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

This following code snippet could help you out. I am not even sure what you are doing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestFrameSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        frame.setSize(new Dimension(450, 400));
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
//        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel question = new JLabel("But that's whole code... Those 3 lines are whole code ");
        question.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.add(question);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + " : " + frame.getHeight());
    }
}
```